# How do I link a MySQL table's columns to columns is other tables?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database with a table called uploads set up. The table has the following columns:
id (PK), video, audio, image.

I have 3 other tables set up (videos, audios, images) in the same database. They each have the following columns:
videos: id (PK), video
audios: id (PK), audio
images: id (PK), image

Is it possible to have the first table's columns automatically fill with whatever data is in the corresponding other tables.

For example: If i added 'image.jpg' to the image column in the images table, 'image.jpg' would automatically be added to the image column in the uploads database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mysql triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) will help you to solve your problem

If you create your table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `uploads` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `audio` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `video` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

You can use something like this:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER populate_after_insert
AFTER INSERT
   ON uploads FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
    DECLARE latestAudio varchar(50);
    DECLARE latestVideo varchar(50);
    DECLARE latestImage varchar(50);

    SELECT uploads.audio FROM uploads GROUP BY id DESC LIMIT 1 INTO latestAudio;
SELECT uploads.video FROM uploads GROUP BY id DESC LIMIT 1 INTO latestVideo;
    SELECT uploads.image FROM uploads GROUP BY id DESC LIMIT 1 INTO latestImage;

    INSERT INTO images(id, image) VALUES(null, latestImage);
    INSERT INTO audios(id, audio) VALUES(null, latestAudio);
    INSERT INTO videos(id, video) VALUES(null, latestVideo);
END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: @Matt Simoncavage of course you can improve the code of that trigger, but at least you have smth to start with ;)